# Random URL with an expiration date (Django)

Tags: django, url

The idea is to generate a time limited random URL and send it to an unregistered person.
what is the proper way to do it? I'm using Django for a few weeks now and have no clue how to perform it.

Thanks

models.py

```
class Address(models.Model):
    """An address"""
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text


class InstructionsStep(models.Model):
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    order = models.IntegerField()
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
```

view.py

```
@login_required
def steps_view(request,address_id):
    address = Address.objects.get(id=address_id)
    if address.owner != request.user:
        raise Http404

    steps = address.instructionsstep_set.all()
    context = {'address': address, 'steps': steps}
    return render(request, 'instructions/steps.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('address/<int:address_id>/', views.steps_view, name='steps'),]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a sketch of what needs to happen.

1. Create a User record in "unregistered" state.
2. Generate a random (and non-guessable) identifier.
3. Store the random identifier in a Callback record along with an expiration date, the key for the User record.
4. Generate a URL that includes the random identifier.

Then you need to define the Django code to handle the GET request when the user visits the URL.  It needs to:

1. Lookup the Callback record.  If that fails, then give the user an error page.
2. Check that it hasn't expired.  If it fails, tell them "you took too long".
3. Display the page for the user to complete of confirm the registration (or whatever).  This may have the same URL (as a POST request) or a different one.

Then you need to define the Django code to handle the POST request.  It needs to:

1. Complete the registration by updating the User record.
2. Remove the Callback record.

Finally, you need something that will periodically scan all outstanding Callback records and remove any that have expired.  Typically you would also remove the corresponding User record.

---

Note:  If you do some searching, you should be able to find existing Django libraries to do this ... and save yourself the effort of coding it yourself.  (But I'm not going to give you a recommendation.)